# Errores en c++ nowscope

Tags: c++, scope

Alguno sabe como solucionar el error nowscope?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo seria inicializar la función 'ecuacion' arriba de la funcion 'main', pero para que no te confundas por ahora, solo copia la función 'ecuacion' y ponla arriba de la función 'main'. Y otra cosa, tienes que darle un valor a la funcion ecuacion, en tu caso no estas retornando nada, asi que pon:' **void** ', antes de 'ecuacion'.

Comment: Soy daltónico y no puedo leer bien el código de la imagen; además el código en imagen no se puede copiapegar, ni se puede compilar ni se pueden buscar palabras sobre el... así que el código en imagen no sirve para nada. Además, esta es una página de programación, no de capturas de pantalla: publica tu código, no una foto del mismo.

Comment: Intenta no poner imágenes donde debería ir código, consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada tienes que poner lo que devuelve tu función, en este caso es void (porque no devuelves nada), luego, tienes que declarar la función ecuación antes de usarla, (como te han dicho en los comentarios no deberías subir una captura tienes que subir el código copiado y pegado), la declaración es antes del main y quedaría tal que así:

```cpp
//Esta sería la solución para tu problema
void ecuacion(double c, double x, double y);
int main(){
//(aquí estaría tu main)
}
void ecuacion(double c, double x, double y){
//(aquí estaría definida la funcion)
}
```

De forma alternativa puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```cpp
void ecuacion(double c, double x, double y){
//Aquí defines la función
}
int main(){
//Tu main
}
```

Y para la próxima vez mejor sube el código pegado para que se pueda ver mejor.